# NoteID in lotus notes view defaluts to NT00000000

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a form with a computed when composed field containing @NoteID in it.

I then want to display that field in a view which is being exported to Oracle ( the NoteID is acting as a key)

The problem is sometimes during document creation the field stores the NoteID value but the view displays NT00000000

Any idea the cause, and how can I refresh the documents with the issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can't get the real note id of a document until *after* the document is saved, so `@NoteID` in a field won't produce a useful result until after saving.

I suggest not using a field at all, and instead having the view column formula as `@NoteID`.

Also: Don't rely on note id if you have replicas of the database.
The same document in a different replica can have a different note id.
If you need an id represented as a string that remains the same across all replicas, use the formula `@Text(@DocumentUniqueID)`.

Comment: It's just a bad idea to use NoteIDs as durable unique identifiers, period. I believe NoteIDs can also change if you do a copy-style compact.